# Whats the right way to store JSON in a database with Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have JSON data I want to store in a database. Ideally, the data should be automatically decoded when I retreive from the database and automatically encoded when I store in the database.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Accessors** and **Mutators**, for an attribute called *foobar* add these two functions in your Eloquent model:

```
public function getFoobarAttribute($value){
    return json_decode($value);
}
public function setFoobarAttribute($value){
    $this->attributes['foobar'] = json_encode($value);
}
```